# Fragment Specific onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I am using ActionBarSherlock and a TabViewPager inside the new version of my application and I am trying to perform certain code **ONLY** when a certain tab is active. First off, let me show you how I am setting up my TabHost and adding the Fragments to it.

```
 private void intialiseViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment2.class.getName()));
    if (appVersionV3()) {
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, TabFragment3.class.getName()));
    }

    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

/**
 * Initialise the Tab Host
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Calculator"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Calculator", TabFragment1.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tracker"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tracker", TabFragment2.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    if (appVersionV3()) {
        TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Food List"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("FoodList", TabFragment3.class, args)));
        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    }

    // Default to first tab
    //this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

}

private static void AddTab(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

My first thought was to call a fragment's method from the Activity onTabChanged, but what doesn't work. See my attempt below - all it does is Force Close the app, I can get a log for this crash if needed.

```
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    mTabHost.getCurrentTabView().invalidate();

    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    if (pos == 1) {
        TabFragment2 tabFragment = (TabFragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tracker");

tabFragment.calculatePoints();
        }
    }
```

---

It also seems that the Fragment's onResume gets called as soon as the Main Activity is started so I cannot call fragment specific code inside of there to detect the change.

My only other thought was to use `onResumeFragments()` but that doesn't seem to be defined for the type `SherlockFragment` - not sure if thats an error on ActionBarSherlock's fault or if that's how it is supposed to be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the exception you get when using the `onTabChanged`? It is a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Yes it is a NullPointerException - I thought I was originally not referencing Tab2 correctly, but the proposals fills with aall my functions/methods in that Fragment.

Comment: I didn't quite get your comment. What is null in the callback? My assumption is that the `tabFragment` variable is `null` because the fragment manager doesn't find it(if this is the case, then please post your `ViewPager`'s adapter code). If another variable is null and throws that exception point it out and give more details about its use.

Comment: Also, if the fragment is null and your adapter is based on a list of fragments, can't you simply get the position in `onTabChanged` and retrieve the fragment from that list?

Comment: This is the exception it throws when trying to call `tabTracker.calculatePoints()` from the Main Activity. http://pastebin.com/0FWi6u5a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone mentioned that since my Fragments are in a list and to just get the Fragment I needed from the list. I initialized my List/Vector globally and then was able to retrieve the Fragment from the list and call its respective functions as needed on the tab change and it works like a charm.

```
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    mTabHost.getCurrentTabView().invalidate();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    // calculatePoints on TabChange
    if (pos == 1) {
        TabFragment2 fragTrack = (TabFragment2) fragments.get(1);
        fragTrack.calculatePoints();
        fragTrack.createAndFillDatabase();
    }

    else if (pos ==2) {
        TabFragment3 fragFoodList = (TabFragment3) fragments.get(2);
        fragFoodList.createAndFillDatabase("none");
    }

    this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```